# Why can I no longer reply from Messages notifications in macOS Big Sur?

Tags: messages, notifications, big-sur

I have recently upgraded to macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 from Catalina 10.15.7.

Now, when I receive a Message, I get the notification but I no longer reply through it. This used to work in Catalina.

I found no useful options in System Preferences > Notifications nor in Messages > Preferences.

Any idea why this is happening and/or what I could do to solve this?
It's a very important feature for my everyday workflow at the Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reply, it's just not intuitive. When you receive the notification, click the dropdown option to expand/show more and it will give you a text field which you can type in.

I've filed this in Apple's bug-report system as FB8619443

Comment: I can't believe this. WHY?? There's still no way around it right?

Comment: Correct, this is certainly "working as intended"